# How to add timestamp (or hash) request parameter for css or js files to the NextJS 12 build file.js?ts=[timestamp]

Tags: typescript, next.js

I need to have opportunity to have the next form of js and css file names after build in NextJs app:
./path/file.js?ts=[timestamp]
./path/file.css?ts=[timestamp]

Answer (score 0):

I found the next solution:

1. Create _document.tsx and create the class with inherit from Document.

```
class StaticDocument extends Document {
  render () {

    return (
      <Html>
        <CustomHead />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

2. Prepare CustomHead that extends from Head. I found the next functions on the library for Head class and overwrote they: getDynamicChunks, getScripts, getCssLinks:

```
declare type DocumentFiles = {
  sharedFiles: readonly string[];
  pageFiles: readonly string[];
  allFiles: readonly string[];
};

const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
function getDynamicChunks(context: any, props: any, files: DocumentFiles) {
  const { dynamicImports , assetPrefix , isDevelopment , devOnlyCacheBusterQueryString , disableOptimizedLoading , crossOrigin ,  } = context;
  return dynamicImports.map((file: any)=>{
    if (!file.endsWith('.js') || files.allFiles.includes(file)) return null;
    console.log('file', file);
    return React.createElement('script', {
      async: !isDevelopment && disableOptimizedLoading,
      defer: !disableOptimizedLoading,
      key: file,
      src: `${assetPrefix}/_next/${encodeURI(file)}${devOnlyCacheBusterQueryString || ('?ts=' + timestamp)}`,
      nonce: props.nonce,
      crossOrigin: props.crossOrigin || crossOrigin
    });
  });
}

function getScripts(context: any, props: any, files: DocumentFiles) {
  let ref;
  const { assetPrefix , buildManifest , isDevelopment , devOnlyCacheBusterQueryString , disableOptimizedLoading , crossOrigin ,  } = context;
  const normalScripts = files.allFiles.filter((file)=>file.endsWith('.js'));
  const lowPriorityScripts = (ref = buildManifest.lowPriorityFiles) == null ? void 0 : ref.filter((file: any)=>file.endsWith('.js'));
  return [
    ...normalScripts,
    ...lowPriorityScripts
  ].map((file)=>{
    return React.createElement('script', {
      key: file,
      src: `${assetPrefix}/_next/${encodeURI(file)}${devOnlyCacheBusterQueryString || ('?ts=' + timestamp)}`,
      nonce: props.nonce,
      async: !isDevelopment && disableOptimizedLoading,
      defer: !disableOptimizedLoading,
      crossOrigin: props.crossOrigin || crossOrigin
    });
  });
}

class CustomHead extends Head {
  getDynamicChunks(files: DocumentFiles): (JSX.Element | null)[] {
    return getDynamicChunks(this.context, this.props, files);
  }
  getScripts(files: DocumentFiles): JSX.Element[] {
    return getScripts(this.context, this.props, files);
  }

  getCssLinks(files: DocumentFiles) {
    const { assetPrefix , devOnlyCacheBusterQueryString , dynamicImports , crossOrigin , optimizeCss , optimizeFonts ,  } = this.context;
    const cssFiles = files.allFiles.filter((f)=>f.endsWith('.css'));
    const sharedFiles = new Set(files.sharedFiles);
    // Unmanaged files are CSS files that will be handled directly by the
    // webpack runtime (`mini-css-extract-plugin`).
    let unmangedFiles: any = new Set([]);
    let dynamicCssFiles = Array.from(new Set(dynamicImports.filter((file)=>file.endsWith('.css'))));
    if (dynamicCssFiles.length) {
      const existing = new Set(cssFiles);
      dynamicCssFiles = dynamicCssFiles.filter((f)=>!(existing.has(f) || sharedFiles.has(f)));
      unmangedFiles = new Set(dynamicCssFiles);
      cssFiles.push(...dynamicCssFiles);
    }
    let cssLinkElements: any[] = [];
    cssFiles.forEach((file)=>{
      const isSharedFile = sharedFiles.has(file);
      if (!optimizeCss) {
        cssLinkElements.push(React.createElement('link', {
          key: `${file}-preload`,
          nonce: this.props.nonce,
          rel: 'preload',
          href: `${assetPrefix}/_next/${encodeURI(file)}${devOnlyCacheBusterQueryString || ('?ts=' + timestamp)}`,
          as: 'style',
          crossOrigin: this.props.crossOrigin || crossOrigin
        }));
      }
      const isUnmanagedFile = unmangedFiles.has(file);
      cssLinkElements.push(/*#__PURE__*/ React.createElement('link', {
        key: file,
        nonce: this.props.nonce,
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: `${assetPrefix}/_next/${encodeURI(file)}${devOnlyCacheBusterQueryString || ('?ts=' + timestamp)}`,
        crossOrigin: this.props.crossOrigin || crossOrigin,
        'data-n-g': isUnmanagedFile ? undefined : isSharedFile ? '' : undefined,
        'data-n-p': isUnmanagedFile ? undefined : isSharedFile ? undefined : ''
      }));
    });
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && optimizeFonts) {
      cssLinkElements = this.makeStylesheetInert(cssLinkElements);
    }
    return cssLinkElements.length === 0 ? null : cssLinkElements;
  }
}
```

I found all lines that responsible to create links and I pushed  additional code with timestamp: ('?ts=' + timestamp).

3. I debuged it and _documents.tsx runs on npm run dev. And it also runs on build process. But build process for _document.tsx consists of 2 steps: a)  build to .next folder and b) _document.js executes only on build process. It is not called on npm start.